# How can I create multiple mailto: using a loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mailto

I'm trying to create multiple mailto by using a (each) loop but what I'm getting as a result is only 1 email with the content of the last loop.

Here is my code:

```
var emailBody = ["Email 1", "Email 2", "Email 3"];
$.each(emailBody, function(key, val){
   var mailToInfo = "mailto:myEmail?subject='Email Title'&body=" + val;
   window.location.href = mailToInfo;
});
```

As recommended by @jperry I tried to create a link element for each of the loops and trigger a click using jquery to open each mailto: messages separately but nothing happens.

Here is the code for this attempt:

```
var emailBody = ["Email 1", "Email 2", "Email 3"];
$.each(emailBody, function(key, val){
   $('#emailLinks').append("<a href = 'mailto:myEmail?subject=/'Email Title/'&body=" + val + "class='emailLink'>Link"+key+"</a>";
});

$('.emailLink').trigger("click");
```

Comment: Are you trying to make mailto links? `window.location.href` is just the url of the webpage you're on.

Comment: We are using Outlook 2007 and by linking to "mailto", a new email message is opened with the "Recipient / Subject & Body" content.
What I'm trying to do is, by using a loop I'm trying to create (3) multiple emails with different "Body" contents.

Comment: Added [tag:outlook-2007] tag to your question.

Comment: Have you tried creating link elements in the loop and then after the loop, using jQuery to click them all? I suspect the window.location doesnt work as  the mailToInfo has changed before it is followed.

Comment: @Cristik if you know enough to eliminate something with certainty then remove it, I don't know how much more clearer I could be. I find it very odd that you don't have any answers nor any suggestions for the OP. Surely you have something to add? Can you explain why Outlook 2007 tag has nothing to do with the OP? BTW, this is the last comment you'll see here from me, have fun monitoring tags.

Comment: @jperry I tried using jquery to trigger "click" on link elements and it does not seem to work with a "mailto:" link.  Nothing happens... I tested the link elements by clicking on the link (on the web page) and all 3 of them work seperately. I'm confused...

Answer (score 0):

I did some more research and it seems that Chrome and Firefox (and maybe other browsers) do not allow more than one trigger to mailto at a time.

https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/jQHT2xll9Ic